# Temporal calculations with Java 8 java.time.*

Tags: java, java-time

Let us have `java.time.Instant` - start point of some event, and `java.time.Duration` - duration of this event.

Can I use `java.time.Period` to calculate if another `Instant` belongs to this period? If no - which approach should I use to define it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if `I2` is in `[I1 + D]` where `D` is the duration, `I1` is the instant and `I2` the instant to check?

Comment: Exactly, I'm new with Java 8 time API, so I thought I should use some "period", but if it's not necessary - nevermind.

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin Posted an answer for you using Period. You should only use that when your interval is not an exact duration in seconds (in which case you should use `Duration`) but when it can vary depending on the context (DST, leap years etc.) and you want to make sure it is properly calculated. (For example an event that spans 5 days, during which DST adjustment takes place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the instant `instant` and the duration `duration`, you want to check if the instant `toCheck` belongs to the interval `[instant; instant + duration]`.

For this, you can calculate the duration between `instant` and `toCheck` with [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-). If this duration is positive and it is less than the specified duration then the instant to check is in the wanted interval.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
    Instant toCheck = instant.plusSeconds(5);

    Duration d = Duration.between(instant, toCheck);
    if (!d.isNegative() && d.compareTo(duration) <= 0) {
        System.out.println("is in interval!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! And what about Period - can it be used for such a task?

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin Not exactly. Period and Duration are subtely different. You can refer to the Javadoc of [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) that explains the difference.

Comment: At first glance - not so intuitive, it would be more naturally to have some method in Period to check if Instance belongs to it. Thank you!

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin It is not so intuitive because unfortunately the 'human' perspective of time is not intuitive either. While the machine perspective is a sequential timeline of seconds from Epoch, humans introduce all sorts of exceptions and special cases to synchronise with the physical phenomena of the Earth (daylight saving, leap years, leap seconds etc) which introduce gaps and overlaps. `Period` just tries to abstract that away from you. Nothing stops you from getting the `[instant; instant + period]` and doing the same check. You have to play a little bit more with dates though.

Answer (score 3):

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project includes `java.time` features that didn't make the cut for the JDK. One of these is `Interval`, see the [Javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html).

Using `Interval`, this problem can be written as:

```
Interval iv = Interval.of(start, duration);
boolean contains = iv.contains(instantToCheck);
```

Comment: Thank you for extra solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution based on a start and end `Instant` for a more intuitive comparison:

```
    Instant start     = Instant.now(); // your value
    Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(10);  // your value
    Instant end       = start.plus(duration);

    Instant toCheck   = start.plusSeconds(5); // your value
    if (!toCheck.isBefore(start) && !toCheck.isAfter(end)) 
        System.out.println("is in interval!");
```

Comment: It's almost similar to first one - but thank you, in any case!

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat more contorted example using `Period` as requested by the OP. This is more useful if you want to use `Days`, `Weeks`, `Months` etc. between your Instants and want to make sure daylight saving, leap years etc. are taken care of seamlessly.

```
Instant start = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime eventStart = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(start, ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime eventEnd = eventStart.plus(Period.ofDays(5));
Instant end = eventEnd.toInstant();

Instant toCheck = start.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

if (!toCheck.isBefore(start) && !toCheck.isAfter(end))
{
  System.out.println("Instant to check is between start and end");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification!